# erlang: distinguish proplists vs. lists of proplists

Tags: list, erlang, key

I write a function which gets `proplists` or `list` of proplists anf key.
if the input is proplists I just use `proplists:get_value` to find a value corresponding to key. But if the input is lists of proplists I need to iterate over all its elements. and look for key in each of them.
I amnot sure how to distinguish `lists` vs. `proplists`. `lists:is_list` returns `true` for both of them...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A proplist has elements that are either tuples or atoms. If the first element of a list argument for your case is one of those, you have a proplist, otherwise you have a list of proplists. For example, this code will return either a value or a list of values found for a given key:

```
get_value(_Key, []) -> undefined;
get_value(Key, [KV|_]=PL) when is_tuple(KV); is_atom(KV) ->
    proplists:get_value(Key, PL);
get_value(Key, List) when is_list(List) ->
    [get_value(Key, V) || V <- List].
```

Here's some example output:

```
2> pl:get_value(foo, []).
undefined
3> pl:get_value(foo, [{foo,bar}]).
bar
4> pl:get_value(foo, [[{foo,bar}]]).
[bar]
5> pl:get_value(foo, [[{foo,bar}],[foo],[{foo,baz}]]).
[bar,true,baz]
```

Notice that in the last case, the middle proplist in the second argument has only a key as an atom, with no associated value, so its value in the returned list is `true`.